# Why i+++ works fine but +++i gives error?

Tags: c, operators, post-increment, pre-increment

I have tried some code in `C` language but I have encountered this problem.

```
int i=0;
i=i+++ ++i;   //works fine
//i=i++ +++i;   gives error
```

My confusion is that how `i+++` is running? but `+++i` return error.

Comment: Even if the behavior were not undefined, whatever `i=i+++ ++i;` is *supposed* to mean, there's certainly a clearer way to express it, perhaps `int i = 3;` if that happens to be what you meant.

Comment: While it's good to understand why the second line produces an error, this is terrible coding style. Please avoid such coding style.

Comment: @RSahu I am not using this style but just trying to know some facts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C operators are parsed according to the “longest match” rule. Your first example is parsed as:

```
i = i ++ + ++ i ;

i = (i++) + (++i);
```

Whereas your second example is parsed as:

```
i = i ++ ++ + i ;

i = ((i++)++) + i;
```

The result of the post-increment operator is an *rvalue*, a copy of the previous value of the variable that was incremented. Applying another post-increment operator to an rvalue is an error because that operator requires an *lvalue*, intuitively, an expression such as `i` or `*p` that can be assigned to.

Also, this code contains undefined behaviour. You are reading `i` and modifying it without an intervening *sequence point*—`;`, `&&`, `||`, `,`, or `?:`—which means that the program behaviour is unpredictable and will vary across compilers.

Comment: Also known as the "maximal munch" rule.

Comment: It's not just the result of the expression that's unpredictable; the behavior of the entire program is undefined.

Comment: @KeithThompson: That’s true. I meant “the result of the expression” as in “what will happen”, not “the value that will be produced”. Not sure of a better way to phrase that.

Comment: You could replace "the result of the expression" by "the behavior of the program".

Comment: @JonPurdy how behaviour is undefined ,I always getting 3 as answer.

Comment: @Devavrata: You may observe different results with different optimisation settings, or with different compilers. In `i = i++ + ++i`, either `i++` or `++i` may be evaluated first, and the assignment to `i` may happen before, after, or even between the increments. The result may be any value, or a crash, or whatever the compiler implementor wants to do—compilers are allowed to assume your program contains only defined behaviours, and they may transform the program accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Both of those statements yield undefined behavior. However, the reason the first works fine is because your compiler interprets it as `(i++)+ ++i;`, whereas the second line is `i++ ++(+i)`, which makes no sense.